# Does git/bash have any built-in way to commit all the commands and outputs you got into a file and have that automatically committed?

Tags: bash, git

Currently I'm going through some CLI. I want to have a file that includes the commands that I ran before the commit.

```
command: commit message 1
// All commands ran prior to this
output: <output for above command>
command: ls
output: <output for above command>
command: rake bootstrap
output: <output for above command>
command: bundle exec
output: <output for above command>


commit message 2
// All commands ran prior to this
command: mkdir newfile
output: <output for above command>
command: pwd
output: <output for above command>
command: gem install
```

I'm doing this because I'm doing some environmental setup but don't want to commit all the files, yet I want commit the commands that have led to it.

I already know that I can `~/.bash_history` but that lacks:

- doesn't have the output (I understand this is too much of ask, so if this isn't doable, then it's totally fine, but I need to achieve the other requirement)
- doesn't allow me to separate commands and append *per each* commit

I was thinking of using `git hook` before every commit to extract commands from `.bash_history` and then clear the commands after commit, but I'm just asking to see if there's a tidier or built in way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trace the input and output of a terminal session, the typical tool that one uses for this is `script`.  Once run, it starts a shell, and every piece of output is recorded to a file, terminal escape codes and all.

That doesn't separate out your data by commit automatically, but you will have the output of which commands were run, including the truncated commit hash, and if you also save timestamps along with your data, you can then correlate those changes automatically using the reflog (see `git reflog --help`).